# Change text by pressing to it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the `firstname`, `lastname` and a pencil icon beside them on my web page. I need to press to pencil and can change text to another one. Please assist to solve this problem

Here is `html`

```
 <a class="nav-link left-panel-txt" id="left-panel-txt" href="/profile">
     <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"></div>
     <span class="dashboard">Firstname Lastname</span><img src="/static/img/pencil.svg" style="width: 5%; height: 5%; margin-left: 10px;">
 </a>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hey @abby, what exactly are you trying to achieve? What text do you want to change when pencil is clicked? Making changes that will last requires some sort of a database etc. where you would store the changes and the data. Without any place to store this data, the data would change back to the original html content when refreshing the page. If you are new to programming, I highly recommend going back a few steps and starting from the basics. =)

Comment: @erecodes thanks for reply. I need to click to my text(firstname and lastaname) and can change them to another name and lastname. I would like to use ajax. Of course I use PHP and MySQL to store data

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo of what you asked.

There's a label displaying static text `Firstname Lastname` and when you click on the pencil next to it, you have the opportunity to edit that value until you click again the pencil and the value becomes read only.

I slightly changed your html and added jQuery (since you listed it in your question tags) and Fontawesome to add an icon of a pencil (since otherwise your pencil image wasn't available).

```js
function onToggleClick(event){
  if ( $(event.target).hasClass('editing') ){
    $(event.target).removeClass('editing');
    $(event.target).prev('.dashboard').removeClass('editing');
    $('.dashboard').attr('contenteditable', false);
  }
  else{
    $(event.target).addClass('editing');
    $(event.target).prev('.dashboard').addClass('editing');
    $('.dashboard').attr('contenteditable', true);
  }
}

$(document).ready(()=>{
  $('.edit_toggle').click(onToggleClick);
});
```

```css
.dashboard{
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.dashboard.editing{
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.edit_toggle i{
  pointer-events: none;
}

.edit_toggle{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.edit_toggle.editing{
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dashboard">Firstname Lastname</div>
<div class="edit_toggle">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i>
</div>
```